# How to change TAB font size in ANY BROWSER

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, safari

I just can't work near PCs anymore my eyes hurt - I am developer. I use browser a lot.
I tried all of them: IE, Safari, FF, Chrome - they all are bad at the most simplest thing - **large font size for tabs.**

Please don't suggest me changing resolution or change DPI sizes - these are not solutions at all.

I don't care if Chrome loads 14 ms faster than browser X, if I spent 5000 ms trying to determine what the hell that tiny tab is for. I already have -2.00 - and this is stress for my eyes.

Numerous threads on Google, some magic dances in Firefox, didn't find anything for safari. Is it time for Linux already?

Maybe there is some genius guy who wrote plugin to save my vision?

Comment: I recommend Firefox due to the fact that it uses XUL/CSS for its UI. You can customize how any part looks, basically.

Comment: how exactly? any reasonable resource?

Comment: @Aubergine I am my own resource. ;)

Comment: that is definitely good for you :-) However I would like to see universal solution that would fit any poor soul like mine

Comment: I'd be very interested to see an answer from @iglvzx as well. This is a problem I deal with too.

Comment: @RandolphWest You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit your Firefox profile's [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) or use the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on to define the following CSS rule:

```
#tabbrowser-tabs
{
    font-size: ... !important;
}
```

Where `...` is replaced with a valid [font-size value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp).

### Example:

```
#tabbrowser-tabs
{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

[image: tabs]

### Video Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAhzZuhN61E

---

**PS:** If you want to also edit the font size of the **List all tabs** popup menu, the CSS selector is:

```
#alltabs-popup menuitem
```

---

**PPS:** Once you've increased the size of your tab's text, you can also increase the width of each tab to accommodate:

```
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned]) 
{
    min-width: ... !important;
    max-width: ... !important;
}
```

Where `...` is replaced with a valid [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) or [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) value. Play around with these values to get different effects! *Note: Pinned tabs will remain the same size.*

### Example:

```
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned]) 
{
    min-width: 400px !important;
}
```

[image: wide tabs]

Comment: I tried however it didnt work - created `chrome' added css - no effect at all :-\ C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\chrome Maybe I've done something wrong? Update: such a lovely picture - my dream

Comment: +1. Works on my machine (latest FF on latest OS X).

Comment: hmm, why does this happen to me, I will keep trying... :-)

Comment: @Aubergine Try the Stylish add-on, it works the same way, but is easier to use.

Comment: Stylish works! YeaY! Can I make tab names appear in full as it gets hidden under dots? like   'beer is...' it misses great.

Comment: @Aubergine Done! :)

Comment: you know what? You are WONDER :-D