# Reduced font size of tabs and menu in chrome 74 new version

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts, browser-tabs

I updated the version of chrome to 74.

The new version of chrome reduced the font size in the tabs titles and the menu font.
I saw solution for firefox, but not chrome.

How can I Increase them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change TAB font size in ANY BROWSER](https://superuser.com/questions/405187/how-to-change-tab-font-size-in-any-browser)

Comment: The solution over there is for firefox. I want chrome

Comment: You can still use [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) chrome extension to achieve the same results in Firefox.

Comment: Again. I want to change the size in chrome browser and not in firefox..The settings over there are for firefox. If you have a solution for chrome please answer.

Comment: I'll try to use that solution on Chrome and i'll give you some feedback

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The settings are connected to your Windows settings.

To change **ONLY** the text relevant to chrome text at menu, do the following:

1) Right click on Desktop and choose Display settings.

2) Choose Advanced Display Settings.

3) Choose Advanced change in text size and other items

4) In the combo box, Choose Message box, and increase the font.

That's it :)

Comment: Currently this is the only solution I know about. However, the problem with this solution is that, as soon as you put your Windows Text Scaling to anything other than "100%", then the text becomes quite blurry. Completely unacceptable, IMHO! Also, the number of offered choices of Windows Text Scaling that you can choose, is way too limited. like, 125%, 150% and 200% and that's it. With the arrival of 4K and 8K screens I do hope that Microsoft will eventually wake up and smell the coffee!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it on mine by running Chrome in Compatibility mode for Windows 7.
find your Chrome Shortcut (I have mine on my desktop
1: Right click on Chrome Shortcut

2: Click "Properties

3: Select Compatibility Tab

4: Check "Run this Program in compatibility mode for" checkbox

5: Select "Windows 7" in the dropdown.

6: Select "Apply"

I reopened Chrome and the Tab Headers and Chrome Header font size is normal again.